# My function is not called when i resolve a promise

Tags: javascript, function

My function residents() returns an array from an API, the function getTatooineResidents() is supposed to create a new promise that executes residents() when the promise is resolved

```
const superagent = require('superagent')
const residents=()=>{
    superagent.get('https://swapi.co/api/planets/1/')
                        .then(res => 
console.log(res.body.residents))
                        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    return residents                         
}
residents()

const getTatooineResidents=()=>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if(3 > 2) resolve(residents())//instead of executing residents() it just writes the body of the function
        reject('I am broken!')
      })
}
```

Instead of executing the function residents() when i call getTatooineResidents() it returns the body of the function, shouldn't the parentheses call the function when i resolve the promise?

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: 
          The function should a return promise which resolves with an array of urls for the residents of Tatooine like : 
        [array of URLS] 
          the promise that was returned from you function resolved with: ()=>{
    superagent.get('https://swapi.co/api/planets/1/')
                        .then(res => console.log(res.body.residents))
                        .catch(err => console.log(err))
return residents                         
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. You wrote a function called `residents` and it has one return statement. The return statement inside this function returns the value `residents`, which is a function. So the function is returning itself. You seem in your question to know the difference between the function value (no parens) and a function call (with parens), so maybe you just have a typo, or you misplaced your return statement (a common problem). Are you getting anything console.logged?

Comment: If i write a string instead of residents() in `if(3 > 2) resolve(residents())
        reject('I am broken!')` it consoles.log that string, so it is working, but it doesn't execute the function residents()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing `res.body.residents` to console and not doing anything with it.

What you are returning is the function itself `const residents`.
Thats why it returns the function body

Instead you want return the actual response data from the promise.

```
const residents= () => {
  let responseResidents = superagent.get('https://swapi.co/api/planets/1/')
                      .then(res => res.body.residents)
                      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  return responseResidents 
}
```

Comment: when i do that i get `undefined` instead of the body of the function

Answer (score 0):

`residents` is not returning a Promise, you need to remove all code after and including `.then`

```
return superagent.get('https://swapi.co/api/planets/1/')
```

Now you can call `getTatooineResidents()` and apply an extra then after it.